# Scrolling in Overleaf

Tags: overleaf

When I'm writing in Overleaf I can scroll the editor using arrows or <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PdDn</kbd>. But I don't know how to scroll the PDF viewer without using the mouse. I know I can click on the PDF viewer and then use arrows but I don't want to leave the editing window.

Are there:

1. Shortcuts for scrolling the PDF viewer while I am editing.
2. A way to sync editor with PDF viewer, i.e. when I move in the editor the PDF viewer follows along.

Comment: I don't think you can make it auto-sync the pdf but the left and right arrows in the dividing bar  will sync the pdf to the current code cursor position so if you click one then the other you can scroll the pdf without losing your editor position.

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome instead of Firefox (Ubuntu 20.04) fixed the issue for me. Not a great solution, but at least a hint on how to get around it temporarily.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How did switching to Chrome solve the issue? Does Chrome have a way of scrolling the Overleaf preview with the keyboard while focused on the source editor, and/or to sync the preview position automatically while you are moving around in the editor?